# Stored Procedure in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure for creating login into SQL Server. The stored procedure is complied successfully but I am getting error when I am executing the stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_login_1
    (@userId varchar(15), 
     @passwd varchar(15), 
     @db varchar(15))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(1000)

    SET @stmt = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @userId + 
                ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @passwd + ', ' + 
                ' DEFAULT_DATABASE = ' + @db + '; ' +
                'CREATE USER' + @userId + 
                ' FROM LOGIN ' + @userId + ';' +
                'ALTER ROLE groupAdmin ADD MEMBER' + @userId + ';'

    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt;
END;

exec dbo.sp_login_1 @userId='user1', @passwd ='pwd', @db ='dbo.myDB';
```

The following error is displayed.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 159
> Incorrect syntax near 'pwd'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 159
> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: SQL Server's programming language is **T-SQL** (not PL/SQL - that's Oracle's)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Both your statements `CREATE USER` as well as `ADD MEMBER` don't have a space after the command - so you'll get `CREATE USERJohnDoe` and `ADD MEMBERJohnDoe` - that definitely needs to be fixed ....

Comment: That procedure is terribly open to injection as well; you are sanitising your values before you inject them into your dynamic statement.

Comment: [how to store passwords in a database](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/store-password-database/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add single quotes for the password field. Best to do this with `QUOTENAME`

```
SET @stmt = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@userId) + 
                ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@passwd, '''') + ', ' + 
                ' DEFAULT_DATABASE = ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + '; ' +
                'CREATE USER' + QUOTENAME(@userId) + 
                ' FROM LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@userId) + ';' +
                'ALTER ROLE groupAdmin ADD MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(@userId) + ';'
```

The reason the error message refers to `pwd` (which is not in the script) is because it clearly passed the `pwd` as a `@passwd` parameter.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock That's right. I will edit the answer

Comment: What about someone who's password is `I'mTheBest123!`?

Comment: @Larnu you are really great for creating challenges. I think that `sys.sp_executesql` should be used. Please advise

Comment: The problem is that your solution *assumes* no injection attacks or single quotes in the password. You need to be properly quoting/escaping the passed values to avoid injection attacks and errors

Comment: Should it be done by the programmer in data entry?

Comment: I would never trust the data passed from a user/application in a procedure.